# how to create function in postgres that returns rowcounts between tables given as parameters

Tags: postgresql, function, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

I am having trouble returning the expected value using the below function in postgres and I am unsure what I am doing wrong.

function:

```
create or replace function check_row_diff(_table_minuend varchar(255), _table_subtrahend varchar(255))
returns bigint as $$
declare 
    v_num numeric;
BEGIN
    execute format ('SELECT
        (select count(*) from %s)
      - (select count(*) from %s) AS Difference', _table_minuend, _table_subtrahend);
return v_num;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

then running a select, returns "NULL"

```
select check_row_diff('table_1', 'table_2');
```

using a "perform" statement just returns an error. running this as an SQL query returns the correct results. Table_1 (name obfuscated) has 4,568 records and table_2 (name obfuscated) has 2,284 records:

```
select 
(select count(*) from table_1)
- (select count(*) from table_2) as difference
```

returns a count of 2,284. I need this check to work because I am coding in python a middleware application that allows our systems to integrate to a cloud SaaS. I am using "working" tables and "golden" tables to ensure the data feed everyday is successful and records are not missing as this will integrate to many internal systems. I am not able to use UPSERT/MERGE in the version of postgres as the DB platform is SaaS cloud hosted in a serverless design (third party managed underlying instance). this function will be called as part of the data validation module prior to updating the "golden" tables and then delivering the data feeds to downstream systems.

please let me know if you need more information on the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of `execute()` should be assigned to the variable using `into:`

```
create or replace function check_row_diff(_table_minuend text, _table_subtrahend text)
returns bigint as $$
declare 
    v_num numeric;
begin
    execute format ('select
        (select count(*) from %s)
      - (select count(*) from %s)', _table_minuend, _table_subtrahend)
    into v_num;
    return v_num;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

Comment: awesome thank you! I think I had tried using into and had an errant semi-colon so I thought it was incorrect syntax. works perfectly!